# Can you freeze gravy?

Tags: freezing

I made gravy for supper today and I have more than we can eat. So I was wondering if it was possible to freeze gravy after it has cooled down in the fridge. If it is possible than what would be the best method to approach it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you freeze it, the gravy *may* separate or curdle after thawing. Stir well, though, and it should be fine.

Cooked meat will be less dry if frozen in a bit of gravy... so if you have any leftover meat, that would be a great way to save both.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that should give you any problem. I've seen plenty of frozen pot pies, for example, and those have what is essentially gravy as part of the sauce. I'd say just put it in a freezer bag, squeeze out the air, and freeze away.